# Combining many routes using one switch statement

Tags: javascript, express, express-router

I am creating an app for production use and would like to combine several routes using one switch statement. I currently use it in development and it works perfectly, however I have not seen this approach used before, and would like to know if there is a reason.
Is there any issue using this approach? If so, really looking for the *why* in the answer.

This is what I'd like to do instead of creating multiple routes.

```
router.post('/save', auth, async (req, res)=>{
    switch(req.body.action) {
        case 'user':
            result = await asyncSaveUser(req.body.data);
            break;
        case 'order':
            result = await asyncSaveOrder(req.body.data);
            break;
        default:
            result = {success:false, data: 'not valid action'};
            break;     
    }
    return res.status(200).json(result);
})
```

In the API I would create an action.

```
url: {baseUrl}+'/save'
body: {
    "action":"user",
    "data": {"fn": John, "ln": Doe}
}
```

Comment: I would recommend following SoC (Separation of Concerns). To each, their own. Create a route for user and one for order. I'm sure both of them handle completely different logic and entities and should be handled separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two concerns:

- That one function will tend to get fairly large over time. Mind you, you've already isolated the logic into separate functions (I'll come back to that in a moment).
- Saving a user and saving an order are fundamentally different operations, but if the URL is `/save` either way, that makes logging, reporting, etc. harder. The difference (user vs. order) is buried in the POST data, rather than being in the URL.

If you *do* do it all in one function, [route parameters](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters) can address the logging, etc., concern. E.g.:

```
router.post('/users/:action', async function (req, res) { // Added `async`, since you're using `await`
    switch(req.params.action) {
        case 'user':
            result = await asyncSaveUser(req.body.data);
            break;
        case 'order':
            result = await asyncSaveOrder(req.body.data);
            break;
        default:
            result = {success:false, data: 'not valid action'};
            break;     
    }
    return res.status(200).json(result);
})
```

Coming back to avoiding letting this function get overlong: You might use a dispatch object:

```
const actionDispatch = {
    action: async asyncSaveUser(data) {
        // ...
    },
    user: async asyncSaveUser(data) {
        // ...
    }
};
function invalidAction() {
    return {success:false, data: 'not valid action'};
}

router.post('/users/:action', async function (req, res) {
    const actionFunction = actionDispatch[req.params.action] || invalidAction;
    const result = await actionFunction(req.body.data);
    return res.status(200).json(result);
});
```

Of course, the `actionDispatch` object could start getting overlong. You might break it up more, the downside to that being maintenance (having to list the functions in it when they're defined elsewhere).

---

Side note: Beware of passing an `async` function to something (`router.post`) that doesn't understand what it returns (a promise). If you do that, you pretty much have to wrap the entire body in `try`/`catch` to handle errors (unless there's some middleware handling promises from these handlers).

Comment: *(Doh! Editing error. If you don't see `actionFunction` in `const result = await actionFunction(req.body.data);` in the final `post` above, hit refresh.)*